# Question about animation using different bvh files

Tags: animation

I want to create an continuous animation from 3 different bvh files. For example, my human character runs, then rolls, then jumps. So I guess my question is about combining bvh files into one animation. What is the best approach, animation nodes? Python coding approach is also an option but I haven't done animation this way before. I need some advice.

Comment: Investigate the Nonlinear Animation editor in Blender. That's what it's for!  [This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxdPtVAz6Do) is about using the NLA in Blender.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was looking for! I tried it out but I'm having trouble transitioning between animations. One animation will be performed and then my armature will suddenly teleport to the starting point of the 2nd animation. Still working on a fix